# Unable to create Spotify app playlist view

Tags: spotify, playlist

I'm trying to display a simple playlist view in my Spotify app with the following code:

```
sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var m = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var v = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/views");
var jq = sp.require('sp://XXX/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min');

var pl = m.Playlist.fromURI('spotify:user:d3marcus:playlist:4zPZzImEYkUOVBvxIo42im');
var player = new v.Player();
player.track = pl.get(0);
player.context = pl;
var list = new v.List(pl);
$('XXX').append(list.node);
```

This will result in an empty list view and an error caught in *sp://import/scripts/language.js:44*: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems this have to do with the character set of the manifest file. If i save as utf-8 it will work, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are getting this error because the playlist has not yet loaded when you do `pl.get(0)`. To make sure the playlist model has loaded you could either do

```
pl = m.Playlist.fromURI('spotify:user:d3marcus:playlist:4zPZzImEYkUOVBvxIo42im');
pl.observe(models.EVENT.LOAD, function() {
  player.track = pl.get(0);
  ...
});
```

or

```
m.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:d3marcus:playlist:4zPZzImEYkUOVBvxIo42im", function(pl) {
  player.track = pl.get(0);
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but could you try this :

```
$('YYY').append($(player.node));
$('XXX').append($(list.node));
```

instead of

```
$('XXX').append(list.node);
```

let us know...

Answer (score 0):

For the 1.0 API:

```
require([
  '$api/models',
  '$views/list#List'
], function (models,List) { 

 var addList = function(list) {
    list.load('tracks').done(function(list) {
        list.tracks.snapshot().done(function(trackSnapshot){

            // Make the playlist view
            var multiple_tracks_player = document.getElementById('addedTracksList');
            var playableList = List.forPlaylist(list);
            multiple_tracks_player.appendChild(playableList.node);
            playableList.init();

        });
    });
 }

 exports.addList = addList;
}

// Example of use:
addList(models.Playlist.fromURI(...))
```

I've tested it as used above, so it should work.

I found this in the [tutorial-app available on github](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0) under "Playing music"-section -> "Play a list of tracks"

I hope this is helpfull.